# How to reuse MappedColumnType in Table classes?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

The use of `MappedColumnType` is demonstrated in this example:

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/computer-database/app/dao/ComputersDAO.scala#L21

How can I reuse `dateColumnType` in another table class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, for example, move it to a trait like this:

```
trait DateColumnMapper extends HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  protected val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  import driver.api._

  implicit val dateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Date, Long](
    d => d.getTime,
    d => new Date(d)
  )
}
```

Then you can include this trait in whatever `DAO` or db component you need it:

```
class WhateverDAO
  extends WhateverComponent
  with HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]
  with DateColumnMapper {

  class Whatevers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Whatever](tag, "WHATEVER") {
    def anyDate = column[Option[Date]]("ANYDATE")
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it seems that `dataColumnType` is not brought into extended class. so I receive this error: `could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[java.time.LocalDateTime]`

Comment: The linked example you are referring to uses `java.util.Date`. Your error shows that you are using `java.time.LocalDateTime`. Are you sure you use the correct type?

Comment: Sorry. I changed to use `LocalDateTime` from `Date`. It is the same for `Date` type.

Comment: Ok, can you please update your question and share your code with us?

Comment: Sorry, I'm such an idiot. I used two different data types so far (one is Date and another is LocalDateTime). Your code works like charm. Thank you.